# A full embedding in a finitely complete category

Tags: category-theory

I know that each category can be full embedded in a complete quasicategory.
My question is: a category can be full embedded in a finitely complete category? There is a universal such one (that's a finitely completion) ?

Comment: Presumably you mean one that's finitely complete but not (small) complete?

Comment: I mean finitely complete category not only quasicategory. In other words, if requiring only finite completeness, we can have a category instead of a quasicategory.

Comment: Yes. Take the smallest full subcategory of $[\mathcal{C}, \mathbf{Set}]^\mathrm{op}$ containing the representables and closed under finite limits.